# how to use InfiniteScrollbar in vf page

Tags: visualforce

I have a list of accounts and i want to show all these accounts in my vf page using infinite scrollbar and that should not be done by any remote call ,on page load all the account are store in list and i have to show that list in particular div.  Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: I think doing this all on page load defeats the purpose of the infinite scrollbar?

Comment: can you please tell me how and what is the way of implementation .

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Do you have any code you have tried so far.  Where are you stuck?  Questions that appear to be asking for people to do the work for you are far more likely to be ignored or closed.  If you could add to the post what you have tried and where you are hitting a barrier, you are much more likely to get help.

Comment: @sfdc_ninja As a whole, we're too quick to close questions like these.  This is perhaps a question that could better benefit from edits or suggestions rather than outright closing the question. Edit: I just saw your edits and now know why you voted to close.  However, I think editing the question and adding comments is still the better route.

Comment: @sneha You have to understand, we as a community provide you this help during our own time.  We cannot simply provide you instant code nor satisfaction to solve your problems as soon as you post a reply.  If you want an immediate response and fix, then hire someone else to do the work for you.  Otherwise, we'll be glad to help you on our own time and guide you toward a solution.

Comment: @JamesLoghry, yes you are right.  I am a bit quick on the trigger to close questions like this.  As you eloquently pointed out, we do this on our time and because we want to help others find solutions.  I guess I just have a very quick trigger when I see 'Need answer ASAP', or 'Please give me code', or 'Urgent, need for deadline' etc.  This is meant for people that want to be part of a community, and sometimes its frustrating to think people aren't appreciative of the help others provide.  You are likely right though, immediately closing might be a bit hasty.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use the StandardSetController and its pagination methods.  Joe Ferrero has written up a nice how-to on utilizing the StandardSetController for infinite scrolling here: http://mavens.force.com/conversation/infinite-scrolling-lists-in-visualforce